# Ansible Playbook to create an unattended install of Ubuntu in VM

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04, infrastructure-as-code

I've been trying to create a playbook to do an unattended install of Ubuntu server 18.04.2 using an iso on VmWare.
The playbook will actually create the instance but stops and waits for user input to select the language, keyboard config, etc.
How can I get ansible/vmware to use a preseed.cfg file to set those options so I can create an unattended install?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be starting with the wrong tool. 
Eventually, you will use Ansible, but calling it from Packer.

Start here: https://github.com/geerlingguy/packer-boxes